# Wrapping an ES6 Class Method in a Coroutine

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to make a class method into a coroutine:

```
import co from 'co';

class AClass {
    co(*consutrctor() {
       console.log('is something like this possible?');
    })

    co(*get() {
        console.log('what about this?');
    })

    onlyWay() {
        return co(function* () {
            console.log('this is how I do it now');
        }.bind(this))();
    }
}
```

In python this is easy with a decorator:

```
from asyncio import coroutine

class AClass(object):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        print('some async task')
```

Comment: Babel supports decorators. However, a constructor cannot be a generator.

Comment: @FelixKling oo, I didn't see decorators in there!  What about using async/await as class methods?

Comment: [Seems to be fine](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20async%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a generator function as @FelixKling said but the correct method to do what you try (in my opinion), is this:

```
import co from 'co';

class AClass {
    constructor() {
        const a = this;
        co(function* () {
           // "a" contains a reference to the class.
           console.log(a...);
        });
    }

    *get() {
        // this is a yieldable generator function and you can use "co" here too.
    }

    onlyWay() {
        // still better to use this in my opinion:
        const a = this;
        co(function* () {
            yield a.get();
        });
    }
}
```